# Merge string is not working to display PDF

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf, string, merge

I am using below code to merge two pdf into one page,

**Apex Class**

```
public String pdf {
    get {
        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/demoVF');
        Blob b = pg.getContentAsPDF();
        String pdf1 = EncodingUtil.base64encode(b);
        String pdf2 = EncodingUtil.base64encode(conVersion.VersionData);
        String finalPdf = pdf2 + pdf1;
        return finalPdf;
    }
 }
```

**Vf Page**

```
<apex:page controller="testController">
    <iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,{!pdf}" height="1000px" width="100%"/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48564310/merging-two-pdfs-in-to-single-and-attaching-in-the-email-in-apex

Comment: again same thing, how can i replace iframe with ?